# Can anyone help me find this highlight theme

Tags: flutter, syntax-highlighting

[I found this cool syntax highlighting on dev blog[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwqsN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like modified material theme. Check it out here - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme